# How do I use a function to create many vectors with different names?

Tags: r, function, vector

**Problem**

I want to create many empty vectors of a specific length. Each vector will have a specificed name.

**Desired result**

```
example <- 1:10 # my actual vector length will change occasionally

a <- vector("numeric", length(example))
a[1] <- example[1]

b <- vector("numeric", length(example))
b[1] <- example[1]
...
etc. 


a 
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

b
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

etc
```

**Attempt:**

```
create_vectors <- function(x){
  x <- vector("numeric", length(example))
  x[1] <- example[1]
  }

x <- c("a", "b", "c") # My actual task involves many more vectors
result <- lapply(x, create_vectors)
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)


Error in list2env(result, .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x
```

The above is an artificial example. I have specific names for the vectors I want e.g. "a" would be "total_demand", "b" = "moving_parts" etc.

Comment: Why not keep them in a `data.frame`?

Comment: I suppose the problem is that that wouldn't work when the length of the vectors changes (as indicated in the question). A `list()` might be better suited in that case.

Comment: Thanks "sindri_baldur", you're right. Once I made an empty dataframe, my lines of code reduced by 90%. See my answer below. 

"Where's my towel", I wanted all the vectors to be larger or smaller depending on the length of another column. I don't need all the vectors to be the same size. Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: Programmatically creating different variables (rather than a single container object) is almost always a bad idea. You are just making your data harder to work with. If you go that route, sooner or later you will find yourself confronted with the problem of how to process data given a list of variable names. Note that a list can contain vectors of different lengths, so you are not restricted to using dataframes as containers.

Answer (score 1):

You will need the `assign` command. Here's a revised version of your function

```
create_vectors <- function(name, vector_to_pass){
  vec2 <- vector_to_pass
  varname <- paste(deparse(substitute(name)))
  assign(varname, vec2, env=.GlobalEnv)
  return(vec2)
}
```

The following command should produce a vector `a` in your global environment that has the values of `example`.

```
create_vectors("a", example)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by  sindri_baldur, I realised that making an empty dataframe would be the easiest solution. I don't need each vector to be of different length. Sorry about this guys, I should have  spent more time thinking about the problem.

**Solution:**

```
example <- 1:10
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = length(example))), 
               c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
df[1, ] <- example[1]
df[is.na(df)] = 0
print(df$a)

[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

With the above, I can get both the vectors and dataframe.